# Apache Camel-Quartz : Is it possible to transfer multiple files in a single iteration

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have a camel-configuration as following

```
from("quartz2://myscheduler?cron=0+34/1+17+?+*+TUE&trigger.repeatCount=1")
.pollEnrich("sftp://user@host1/path/DirTest?recursive=true&password=pwd&move=.camel&moveFailed=.error")
.to("sftp://user@host2/DirTest?password=pwd&passiveMode=true&maximumReconnectAtrempts=3");
```

With this configuration camel transfer only one file within the time interval given (in this case 1min). Is it possible to transfer multiple files in a single interval ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't look like poll-enrich supports multiple files. You need to use other components such as the control-bus to do this. See here:
https://qnalist.com/questions/4843799/pollenrich-all-the-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 1):

If you want to schedule to move all new files from one FTP server to another, then you can use the cron scheduler on the FTP directly, so its just

```
from ftp
  to ftp
```

More details here: http://www.davsclaus.com/2013/08/apache-camel-212-even-easier-cron.html

And I think there is some questions here on SO about this, you can try to search.